# How to get information about the Identity parameter value set MaxFailedAccessAttempts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-core-3.1

I use a popular library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, which I configured:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(o =>
            {
                o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            });
            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);

            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<RepositoryContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

For now, `MaxFailedAccessAttempts` is set to 3 tries but may change for the entire application in the future. How can I get this value in Actions? I would like to use the value in action to calculate how many tries are left before the account is locked.

```cs
int attemptsLeft = user.AccessFailedCount - UNKNOWN.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
return Unauthorized($"Wrong password. {attemptsLeft} attempts left.");
```

The solution that I found is initializing `MaxFailedAccessAttempts` and getting in action value from `appsettings.json`, but I don't want to add another field in the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject **UserManager** and get `MaxFailedAccessAttempts` from `Options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts`

```cs
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
public UserController(UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}
.
.
.
int maxFailedAccessAttempts = _userManager.Options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
int attemptsLeft = maxFailedAccessAttempts - user.AccessFailedCount;
return Unauthorized($"Wrong password. {attemptsLeft} attempts left.");
```

Comment: I feel like a blind man. Thanks for pointing out the path that was right under my nose.